Citation about lemma regarding irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ and algebraically independent variables
I have the following lemma I need to use: If $f$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ and $z$ is a root of $f$, then $1, z, z^{2},...,z^{n-1}$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. I need a proof or a citation from a reputable book about this lemma for a project that I am working on that requires this theorem, if anybody can try to help it would be appreciated.

I think it is contained in any book covering abstract algebra. For example, in "Field Theory" by Steven Roman it is Theorem 2.4.1 item 3.

2nd edition btw.

You mean LINEARLY independent over $\mathbf Q$, not algebraically independent!  This is not about algebraic number theory, so that tag is unnecessary.

Assume that $1,z,\ldots,z^{n-1}$ are algebraically dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then you can find rational numbers $b_0,b_1,\ldots, b_{n-1}$ that can't be simultaneously zero such that
$$b_0 + b_1z+\ldots + b_{n-1}z^{n-1} =0$$
Thus $z$ is a root of the polynomial $g(x) = b_0 + b_1x+\ldots+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}$. Since $f$ is irreducible, $\deg(f) > \deg(g)$, two polynomials $f,g$ must be coprime. Since $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is an Euclidean domain, you can find $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $$ af+bg=1.$$Now subtituting $x=z$ gives $ 0 =1$, which is absurd. So  $1,z,\ldots,z^{n-1}$ are algebraically independent.
You can also find various proofs in any algebra books that covers Field theory, as someone commented above. I used Algebra -Springer Edition of Prof. Hungerford - the proof of this is on page 234, theorem 1.6
